# Transform differential equation to get equilibrium position

Tags: differential-equations, replacement

I would like to determine the equation in the equilibrium position.

```
eq = 1/2 g l m Cos[θ[t]] == J (θ^′′)[t]
```

> ```
> 1/2 g l m Cos[θ[t]] == J (θ^′′)[t]
> ```

```
Subscript[proc, e][eq_] := Replace[eq, θ[t] -> θe, ∞]
Subscript[proc, e][eq]
```

> ```
> 1/2 g l m Cos[θe] == J (θ^′′)[t]
> ```

[image: Equation at the equilibrium position with mathematica]

Unfortunately, the second derivative of `theta[t]` is not equal to 0 and so I don't obtain the equation for the equilibrium position.

In maple, as you can see in the following picture, I manage to have the good result.

[image: Equation at the equilibrium position with maple]

Can anyone help me to correct my *Mathematica* code in order to obtain the equation at the equilibrium position?

Answer (score 2):

By replacing using the rule:

```
θ[t] -> θe
```

You are replacing all instances of the expression `θ[t]`.  However, the derivative `θ''[t]` is represented in Mathematica by:

```
Derivative[2][θ][t]
```

(You can see this by using `FullForm`.)  This does not contain `θ[t]`, so no replacement is performed.  What you want to do is replace `θ` with a `Function` like this:

```
θ -> Function[t, θe]
θ -> (θe &)
```

When substituting this into your expression, `Derivative` will be able to evaluate the derivative of the function, which is zero.

Two comments on your code: you probably want to be using `ReplaceAll` like this:

```
processEquation[eq_] := ReplaceAll[eq, θ -> (θe &)]
processEquation[eq_] := eq /. θ -> (θe &)
```

Instead of using `Replace`.  Second, you generally shouldn't `SetDelayed` to expressions with the `Head` `Subscript`.  That associates the definition of your function with `Subscript`.  You can see that from the results of `Definition[Subscript]`:

```
Attributes["Subscript"] = {NHoldRest}

Subscript[proc, e][eq_] := Replace[eq, θ[t] -> θe,  ∞]
```

Trying to `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` will produce an error, since `Subscript` is protected.  **Use non-subscripted names instead**, like I did above.

Comment: Thank for your help.
1) However, may you detail me these codes lines ?
θ -> Function[t, θe]
θ -> (θe &)
I have difficulties to understand these lines.
Isn't there another simplest solution to replace the function theta[t] by a constant as thetae ?

Comment: Read the documentation for `Function`.  Both lines define a rule from `θ` to a function (`Function[t, θe]` or `θe &`) that returns a constant, `θe`, given any argument.  The function `processEquation` applies this rule to its argument.  This is the simplest solution (except for simply applying the rule directly to your equation).

Comment: OK Thank you for your clear explanations.
May you precise me the difference between Replace with infinity in argument and ReplaceAll? Which should I use for my objective ?